# PHP MySQL Insert Query is not Working as Expected

Tags: mysql

I am running into an issue with a PHP program which I am writing, and I cannot pinpoint what the issue is.

Here is the program:

```
   <?php
require 'dbSensorData.php';

$sql = "INSERT INTO `data` (`timeStamp`, `MessageType`, `UniqueID`, `SensorID`, `SoilMoistureOne`, `SoilMoistureTwo`, `SoilMoistureThree`, `SoilMoistureFour`, `SoilMoistureFive`, `SoilMoistureSix`, `SoilTempOne`, `SoilTempTwo`, `SoilTempThree`, `SoilTempFour`, `SoilTempFive`, `SoilTempSix`, `SoilMoistureWM1`, `SoilMoistureWM2`, `SoilMoistureWM3`, `Rainfall`, `WindSpeed`, `WindDirection`, `temperature`, `humidity`) VALUES (CURRENT_TIMESTAMP, \'0010\',\'00000\',\'000\',\'00.00\', \'00.00\', \'00.00\', \'00.00\', \'00.00\', \'00.00\', \'00.00\', \'00.00\', \'00.00\', \'00.00\', \'00.00\', \'00.00\', \'00.00\', \'00.00\', \'00.00\', \'00.00\', \'00.00\', \'00.00\', \'00.00\', \'xxx\')";

    $add = $mysqli->query($sql);

    if ( $add )
    {
        echo "Adding data to DB was Successful";
    }

    else 
    {
        echo "Adding data to DB failed";
    }

?>
```

I am running into an issue with this part of the code in particular:

```
    $sql = "INSERT INTO `data` (`timeStamp`, `MessageType`, `UniqueID`, `SensorID`, `SoilMoistureOne`, `SoilMoistureTwo`, `SoilMoistureThree`, `SoilMoistureFour`, `SoilMoistureFive`, `SoilMoistureSix`, `SoilTempOne`, `SoilTempTwo`, `SoilTempThree`, `SoilTempFour`, `SoilTempFive`, `SoilTempSix`, `SoilMoistureWM1`, `SoilMoistureWM2`, `SoilMoistureWM3`, `Rainfall`, `WindSpeed`, `WindDirection`, `temperature`, `humidity`) VALUES (CURRENT_TIMESTAMP, \'0010\',\'00000\',\'000\',\'00.00\', \'00.00\', \'00.00\', \'00.00\', \'00.00\', \'00.00\', \'00.00\', \'00.00\', \'00.00\', \'00.00\', \'00.00\', \'00.00\', \'00.00\', \'00.00\', \'00.00\', \'00.00\', \'00.00\', \'00.00\', \'00.00\', \'xxx\')";

    $add = $mysqli->query($sql);
```

The code executes, however, the table does not have a new entry added to it, and the code gives the following output:

```
Adding data to DB failed
```

This must mean that $mysqli->query($sql) is returning a false value.

However, when I use the following SQL to insert into the table using PHPMyAdmin, the entry is added into the table without any issues:

```
INSERT INTO `data` (`timeStamp`, `MessageType`, `UniqueID`, `SensorID`, `SoilMoistureOne`, `SoilMoistureTwo`, `SoilMoistureThree`, `SoilMoistureFour`, `SoilMoistureFive`, `SoilMoistureSix`, `SoilTempOne`, `SoilTempTwo`, `SoilTempThree`, `SoilTempFour`, `SoilTempFive`, `SoilTempSix`, `SoilMoistureWM1`, `SoilMoistureWM2`, `SoilMoistureWM3`, `Rainfall`, `WindSpeed`, `WindDirection`, `temperature`, `humidity`) VALUES (CURRENT_TIMESTAMP, \'0010\',\'00000\',\'000\',\'00.00\', \'00.00\', \'00.00\', \'00.00\', \'00.00\', \'00.00\', \'00.00\', \'00.00\', \'00.00\', \'00.00\', \'00.00\', \'00.00\', \'00.00\', \'00.00\', \'00.00\', \'00.00\', \'00.00\', \'00.00\', \'00.00\', \'xxx\')
```

Additionally, here is my dbSensorData.php information, with the actual  password omitted:

```
    <?php
$host = 'localhost';
$user = 'root';
$pass = 'password';
$db = 'SensorData';
$mysqli = new mysqli($host,$user,$pass,$db) or die($mysqli->error);
?>
```

Additionally, here is the command I used to create the MySQL Table:

```
CREATE TABLE `sensorData`.`data` 
(
    `timeStamp` TIMESTAMP NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY,
    `MessageType` INT NOT NULL,
    `UniqueID` VARCHAR(64) NOT NULL,
    `SensorID` VARCHAR(64),
    `SoilMoistureOne` FLOAT,
    `SoilMoistureTwo` FLOAT,
    `SoilMoistureThree` FLOAT,
    `SoilMoistureFour` FLOAT,
    `SoilMoistureFive` FLOAT,
    `SoilMoistureSix` FLOAT,
    `SoilTempOne` FLOAT,
    `SoilTempTwo` FLOAT,
    `SoilTempThree` FLOAT,
    `SoilTempFour` FLOAT,
    `SoilTempFive` FLOAT,
    `SoilTempSix` FLOAT,
    `SoilMoistureWM1` FLOAT,
    `SoilMoistureWM2` FLOAT,
    `SoilMoistureWM3` FLOAT,
    `Rainfall` FLOAT,
    `WindSpeed` FLOAT,
    `WindDirection` VARCHAR(32),
    `temperature` FLOAT,
    `humidity` FLOAT
);
```

Any help with this is greatly appreciated, as I have been stumped by this.

Comment: I **really** doubt you want floating values. You may want `DECIMAL` column types, but floating values come with a raft of calcuation issues as their values are by their true nature, er, floating.

Comment: Thank you for your input.  You are absolutely correct.  I have changed my table so that it stores data as decimal rather than float.  However, this has not resolved the issue, unfortunately.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is there a reason for those escaped quotes? It doesn't work for my with those backslashes in my phpMyAdmin. I had to go through the code and un-unescape those quotes.

```
INSERT INTO `data` (`timeStamp`, `MessageType`, `UniqueID`, `SensorID`, `SoilMoistureOne`, `SoilMoistureTwo`, `SoilMoistureThree`, `SoilMoistureFour`, `SoilMoistureFive`, `SoilMoistureSix`, `SoilTempOne`, `SoilTempTwo`, `SoilTempThree`, `SoilTempFour`, `SoilTempFive`, `SoilTempSix`, `SoilMoistureWM1`, `SoilMoistureWM2`, `SoilMoistureWM3`, `Rainfall`, `WindSpeed`, `WindDirection`, `temperature`, `humidity`) VALUES (CURRENT_TIMESTAMP, '0010','00000','000','00.00', '00.00', '00.00', '00.00', '00.00', '00.00', '00.00', '00.00', '00.00', '00.00', '00.00', '00.00', '00.00', '00.00', '00.00', '00.00', '00.00', '00.00', '00.00', 'xxx')
```

And that query worked for me.

Otherwise you could use `mysqli_error()` ( `$mysqli->error` ) to see [what kind of error MySQLi](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.error.php) throws at you. Might give you a hint as to why it's failing.

Comment: After removing the escaped quotes, the query still failed to work.  I have also tried using mysqli_error(), and it is not providing any output...Very Strange!

Comment: What happens if you add `error_reporting(E_ALL);` at the beginning of the file?

Comment: @claybot make sure your values are aligned with your columns. Looks like you are putting a WindDirection (varchar) into humidity (float). The varchar (xxx) is trying to be converted to float